# How to correctly align structs in C using posix_memalign?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, alignment, posix

I know that there have been many questions about this topic, but I still find myself confused.

I have written this simple program to help me visualize memory alignment in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct S{
  int a;    
  short b;
  char c;
};
int main()
{
    struct S *s;
    posix_memalign((void**)&s, 8, 12) == 0 ? printf("allocation successful"):printf("allocation failed");
    printf("\nlocation of struct:\t%p\n", s);
    printf("\nlocation of int:\t%p\nlocation of short:\t%p\nlocation of char:\t%p\n", &(s->a), &(s->b), &(s->c));
    printf("\nsizeof struct: %lu\n", sizeof(s));
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This is working well, but I am getting confused with the alignments.

Using these arguments (alignment=8 bytes, size=12):

```
allocation successful
location of struct: 0x205e010

location of int:    0x205e010
location of short:  0x205e014
location of char:   0x205e016

sizeof struct: 8
```

The `int` is the largest element of the struct, at 4 bytes. I can see here that the `short` begins 4 bytes later, and the `char` 2 bytes after that. Why isn't there another 2 bytes of padding between the `short` and `char`?

Also, why does the allocation fail if I use an alignment of 4 bytes? Since that is the size of the largest element in the `struct`, shouldn't it work?

```
allocation failed
location of struct: (nil)

location of int:    (nil)
location of short:  0x4
location of char:   0x6

sizeof struct: 8
```

Comment: I'm curious: Why are you allocating a hard-coded `12` bytes rather than `sizeof(struct S)` bytes?

Answer (score 1):

The `char` member can be aligned on any byte boundary; there is never a need to insert padding before a `char` member, even though a compiler could if it wanted to.  The way it is laid out, there is just a single padding byte in the structure.  If there was a gap after the `short` member, the structure would have five bytes of padding, which is wasteful.

The chances are that the minimum alignment that `posix_memalign()` supports is 8 on your machine.  POSIX says it can fail:

> `[EINVAL]`
>       The value of the alignment parameter is not a power of two multiple of `sizeof(void *)`.

Having said that, it looks like `sizeof(void *)` is probably 4 (the addresses you print fit in a 32-bit address space).  Maybe you should print `errno` (and/or `strerror(errno)`) to see what the cause of failure is.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting about the char alignment. I hadn't read that. I don't understand why an alignment of 4 fails, but the int and short are still separated by 4 bytes. printing strerror(errno) just gave me: Success. That is with the alignment set to 4 and size set to 12.

Comment: Also, I am getting that sizeof(void*) is 8 bytes.

Comment: @user2676680: given that `sizeof(void *)` is 8 bytes then you cannot allocate at an alignment that is an odd multiple of 4 bytes; it doesn't meet the requirement specified by POSIX.